# How run batch file from python without subprocess and os module

Tags: python, batch-file

there I'm looking for another module which let me  run a batch file from a Python script. This is just an experiment. I've been trying sys, os, subprocess is there any module more?

```
import sys
sys.argv = ['arg1', 'arg2']
execfile("C:/test.py") 


import os
os.system("C:/test.bat") 


import subprocess
filepath="C:/test.bat"
p = subprocess.Popen(filepath, shell=True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
```

Comment: i like this one a lot: http://amoffat.github.io/sh/ . but in the background it also uses `subprocess` (i think).

Comment: IMO, I think using subprocess is the way to go.

Comment: There is [popen2](http://effbot.org/librarybook/popen2.htm) also